# How can I write Jest test in function without return

Tags: javascript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a calculateDateRange.js to get the list of the past 12 months from now. So how can test it using Jest?

```
export function getDateRange() {
    const today = new Date();
    this.months = [];
    for (let i = -1; i >= 13; i--) {
        const previousMonth = DateTime.add(today, "month", i);
        previousMonth.setDate(1);
        if (previousMonth.getFullYear() >= 2020) {
            this.months.push(dateLong: previousMonth);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of it? How's it used? _That's_ how you test it.

Comment: Any sample code or docs? I am not sure how to write it. Cheers

Comment: Jest has documentation and examples, sure: https://jestjs.io/. How you test that specific function will be driven by why exactly it's like that, which we don't know.